# Do I need both JDK 10 and JDK 8 in my Mac for Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I installed JDK 10 first, then I installed android studio, but I watched a tutorial - convincing me at the moment, I need JDK 8, so I installed JDK 8, afterward, I reinstalled android studio. Do I need both versions of JDKs? My android studio seems running slow. thanks!

Comment: You can keep your JDK 8. Slowness is sometimes a result of poor hardware.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 8, 2018, Android Studio or the command line tools don't work with JDK 10. You only need JDK 8.
Android Studio actually ships with a JDK that you should use. You don't need a separate JDK.

Comment: Other than command line tools, at least can Android Studio build without problems using JDK 10? Also, I want to know if it's safe to upgrade to JDK 9.

Comment: I couldn't make JDK 9 or 10 work with Android studio. My recommendation will be to stick with what Android Studio ships with.